# How to store Date from internet like "2014-12-01T20:00:00Z" in core data

Tags: core-data, nsdate, nspredicate, nsdateformatter, nstimeinterval

How to store Date from internet like "2014-12-01T20:00:00Z" in core data and compare this date with [NSDate Date] using nspredicate. as i am using @((date" >= startDate) && (date <= endDate))..But it fails to match date always..

Comment: What is your problem? Are you unable to turn the string into a NSDate? You might be storing nil in core data because your NSDateFormatter does not work. Use the debugger and try to figure out which part fails.

Comment: How do i convert this @"2014-12-01T20:00:00Z" in NSDate format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store startDate and endDate as NSDate. Predicate for this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@“%@ >= startDate and %@ <= endDate”, [NSDate date], [NSDate date]];
```